# Zoom Video Sdk integration in flutter web

Tags: flutter, zoom-sdk

Is there any way to integrate zoom video sdk in flutter web.
there are good documentation on android and ios,but web is left.
can we integrate it or not(just want some clarity).
Thanks In Advance.

My App should support zoom in android,ios and web(chrome or edge).